# Accessing a parameter via a C++ function object class

Tags: c++, c++11

```
    #include <iostream>

    struct A {
        explicit A(int a) : _a(a) {};
        int _a;
    };

    struct ClassFunction {
        ClassFunction(std::shared_ptr<A> myA) : _myA(myA) {}

        double operator() (int &x,
                           int &g) {
            return 1.0
                   + static_cast<double>(_myA->_a); // offending line
        }
        static double wrap(int x, int g, void *data) {
            return (*reinterpret_cast<ClassFunction*>(data)) (x,g);
        }
        std::shared_ptr<A> _myA;
    };

    int main() {
        int x = 1;
        int g;
        auto myA = std::shared_ptr<A>(new A(int(20)));
        ClassFunction myClassFunction(myA);
        std::cout << ClassFunction::wrap(x,g,NULL) << std::endl;
        return 0;
    }
```

I'm trying to create a function object class `ClassFunction` that takes a `std::shared_ptr<A>` as a parameter, which I then call via the `static` member function `ClassFunction::wrap`.

If I access a data member of `A` as `myA->_a` the program fails to run (it does compile without any complaint, however).

How do I make this work?

Comment: You make it work by not passing a null pointer to `wrap`?

Comment: Why did you write `ClassFunction::wrap(x,g,NULL)` and what did you intend by supplying a null pointer here? Why do you expect that to work?

Comment: It's very similar to the boilerplate code suggested by the optimization library `NLOPT`, "...with a two-line helper function. If your function class is MyFunction, then you could define a static member function:"`static double wrap(const std::vector<double> &x, std::vector<double> &grad, void *data) {
    return (*reinterpret_cast<MyFunction*>(data))(x, grad); }`

Comment: I have absolutely no idea about what the purpose of this whole mess is. Why would you want to use a static function to call a function object you created? You're passing a null pointer, so the static call accesses a null memory location, it's as simple as that. It won't even reach the `operator()` code, it should fail right at the dereference of `data`.

Comment: Do you understand what the code of `wrap` does? What it does with its `data` parameter? Again, what do you expect to get by passing a null pointer there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
std::cout << ClassFunction::wrap(x, g, &myClassFunction) << std::endl;
```

reinterpret_cast< ClassFunction*>(data) is applicable when the data points to instance of ClassFunction class.

Comment: Yes, this is what I wasn't grasping. Thanks!